# Override native nodejs function with nodejs javascript or c++ addon

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I am trying to override the native function of nodejs and make it global. (For example: console / require)

Here is my approaches:

---

**M1** use global

myConsole.js

```
function myConsole() {
  var nativeConsole = console;

  // ... some code


}

myConsole.log = function() {
  nativeConsole.log('It works!');
}

global.console = myConsole; // <-- HERE
```

index.js

```
require('./myConsole.js');
require('./test.js');
```

test.js

```
console.log('Not working. :(');
```

This failed.

---

**M2** direct assignment

myConsole.js

```
function myConsole() {
  var nativeConsole = console;

  // ... some code


}

myConsole.log = function() {
  nativeConsole.log('It works!');
}

*console = myConsole; // <-- HERE
```

index.js

```
require('./myConsole.js');
require('./test.js');
```

test.js

```
console.log('Not working. :(');
```

This also failed.

---

Does anyone know how to override it? Thanks.

**Addition**: I don't have experiences with c++ node module, is it possible to override native code?

[v8 reference](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#static_global)

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there's no way for the `log` function to get to the `nativeConsole` variable. That needs to be changed. I also don't see anything wrong in the global assignment `global.console = myConsole;`

You could try this (which gives you access to the `nativeConsole` variable within your custom function):

```
function myConsole() {
  var nativeConsole = console;

  // ... some code

  return { 
      log : function() {
          nativeConsole.log('something');
      }
  }

}

global.console = myConsole;
```

Comment: This way is a nice one but not the exact one. It needed to call **require('./myConsole.js')** each time. I am currently using this way to handle my script. But I really hope if there is any way to override it ;).

Comment: @goodseller I forgot to add the part that changes the global object, which is what you had in your example.  See edited anser. `global.console = myConsole;`

Comment: It shows the message: **Not working. :(** as I replaced thescript in **myConsole.js**